# Firebase Crashlytics recognises only first added app

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have opened a new Firebase project for an app that already uses Crashlytics without any problems.
I first added an app called "com.myexample.bla".
Then, I opened another app - "com.myexample.bla.debug".
(Of course I also added their respective SHA1 fingerprints).

I put the google-service.json inside `app/` directory.
But specifically the `.debug` app doesn't send anything to Firebase it appears. It's still stuck on `We’ll be listening for your app to communicate with our server`

Yesterday, I tried doing it the opposite way - started new project, then added the debug package, and only then added the release version.
The debug version worked, the release didn't.

It's like Firebase only recognizes the first added app, and ignores the others.